# Mongo $lookup not working after another $group

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation query like this to group the categories which have a post

```
    const categoriesWithPosts = await Models.Post.aggregate([
      {
        $match: { active: true },
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$category",
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'categories',
          localField: '_id',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'category',
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$category',
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$category.parent_id',
          subCategories: {
            $push: '$category',
          },
        },
      },
      // {
      //   $lookup: {
      //     from: 'categories',
      //     localField: '_id',
      //     foreignField: '_id',
      //     as: 'parentCategory',
      //   },
      // },
      // {
      //   $unwind: '$parentCategory',
      // },

    ]);
```

now it works fine till the uncommented lines groups my categories like this

```
[
{
                "_id": "655b01fca9233b324cdc5051",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "_id": "655b05c5198d38433e066970",
                        "parent_id": "655b01fca9233b324cdc5051",
                        "title": "Crafts and Hobbies",
                        "image": "https://images.ctfassets.net/nvayryb6yxxr/7oviwG8t6myzR4DkCSP9gD/037c75622dd6aa8000e633726f48598a/Crafts_and_Hobbies.jpg",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "655b02e6c3246efb0f5174f5",
                        "parent_id": "655b01fca9233b324cdc5051",
                        "title": "Home Decor",
                        "image": "https://images.ctfassets.net/nvayryb6yxxr/5QJRgVkbP2h7WTyfIfRJvN/2d0cf22fb38661ed838769472f6d236f/Home_Decor_Category.jpg",
                        "__v": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
]
```

but when i uncomments the line to look for the parent category it returns an empty array now i dont why it is doing it my mongo has the id i will show but it doesnt fetches it

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "655b01fca9233b324cdc5051"
  },
  "parent_id": "",
  "title": "Home",
  "image": "https://images.ctfassets.net/nvayryb6yxxr/49RTYuPnpuYROSJ7S57Slw/8ff9173435a5e2114a43cad31afa5d45/Home_Category.jpg",
  "__v": 0
}
```

and also will share the category model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const categorySchema = new Schema({
    parent_id: { type: String, default: "" },
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    image: { type: String },
});

const Category = mongoose.model("category", categorySchema);

module.exports = Category;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that the parent_id is a String while the `_id` of `categories` is an `ObjectId` (`$oid`).

You should parse the _id as a String while comparing with parentId. You could do as follows :

```
   {
     $lookup: {
       from: 'categories',
       let : {"parentId" : "$_id"},
       pipeline : [
          {$match : 
              {$expr: 
                  {$eq : [
                      "$$parentId",
                      {"$toString" : "$_id"}
                         ]
                  }
              }
          }
       ],
       as: 'parentCategory',
     },
   },
```

PS: You could do the other way around and parse your parentId as ObjectId but it might returns errors if it doesn't correspond to the format of an ObjectId.